# Ошибка ValueError: All arrays must be of the same length в Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, excel

Я пишу парсер, и данные нужно сохранить в `xlxs`-файл, но при сохранении выводится ошибка. Вот сам код:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'имя': all_names,
                'специализация': all_specialities,
                'стаж': all_stage})
df.to_excel('/home/GorkiiOgurec/fl/pars_doctorov/names.xlsx')
```

При самом первом запуске все заработало, но уже при втором не заработало.

Ошибка:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/GorkiiOgurec/fl/pars_doctorov/parser_doc.py", line 30, in <module>
    df = pd.DataFrame({
  File "/home/GorkiiOgurec/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 636, in __init__
    mgr = dict_to_mgr(data, index, columns, dtype=dtype, copy=copy, typ=manager)
  File "/home/GorkiiOgurec/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/core/internals/construction.py", line 502, in dict_to_mgr
    return arrays_to_mgr(arrays, columns, index, dtype=dtype, typ=typ, consolidate=copy)
  File "/home/GorkiiOgurec/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/core/internals/construction.py", line 120, in arrays_to_mgr
    index = _extract_index(arrays)
  File "/home/GorkiiOgurec/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/core/internals/construction.py", line 674, in _extract_index
    raise ValueError("All arrays must be of the same length")
ValueError: All arrays must be of the same length
```

Answer (score 2):

Похоже, у вас по какой-то причине не равны длины списков all_names, all_specialities и all_stage.

Вставьте перед этим фрагментом кода такую строчку:

```
print(len(all_names), len(all_specialities), len(all_stage))
```

чтобы понять, какой из списков имеет неправильную длину. А потом надо будет смотреть в предыдущем коде, как этот список формируется, и почему его длина неправильная.

Comment: Да спасибо! Нашел проблему.